# Disable VS 2010 format on paste for razor but not c#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'd like to use resharper formatting for all my razor in VS 2010. (because VS indents incorrectly)
So I want to disable VS format on paste for razor however I still would like format on paste ON in c# files.

Is this possible?
(is this possible in VS2012)

Note: I can disable it for c# **and** razor by setting:
`Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > [uncheck] Automatically format on paste`
but I can't disable it just for razor, perhaps there's an extension? or some way to have resharper take control?

Comment: There is no way to do it, here is [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098648/disable-visual-studio-code-formatting-in-razor)

Answer (score 3):

Try going to `Tools | Options -> Text Editor | HTML | Miscellaneous` and turning off `Format HTML on paste`. Haven't tried this myself, but it may work.

Comment: Thank you! This did work for me (in VS 2013). The UX for it is different than in all the other languages so I couldn't spot it before. Cheers!

Comment: thanks you. Of course in vs 2013, its in Tools | Options -> Text Editor | HTML | Advanced | Paste -> Format on paste

Comment: Works in VS 2015 as well.